# Where to store tokens in a xamarin.form application

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have the class below that will be used in a xamarin.forms mobile application
to retrieve the token generated by OAuth(webapi). Once this is generated I need to store
in a place where I can access it again and not generating this all the time.
Where is the best place to store this in the Pcl? I will also want to be able to remove this once
the user logs off.

```
        class LoginService
        {
            public async Task Login(string username, string password)
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = new HttpWebRequest(new Uri(String.Format("{0}Token", Constants.BaseAddress)));
                request.Method = "POST";

                string postString = String.Format("username={0}&amp;password={1}&amp;grant_type=password", 
                HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(username), HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(password));
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postString);
                using (Stream requestStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
                {
                    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }

                try
                {
                    HttpWebResponse httpResponse =  (HttpWebResponse)(await request.GetResponseAsync());
                    string json;
                    using (Stream responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        json = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
                    }
                    TokenResponseModel tokenResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
                    return tokenResponse.AccessToken;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new SecurityException("Bad credentials", ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: [Craig's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62535887/199364), which uses `Xamarin.Essentials SecureStorage class`, is the most up-to-date here (at the time I write this comment). Includes doc link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forms has a built in [Properties](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/application-class/#Properties_Dictionary) dictionary where you can store small bits of persistent data.

```
Application.Current.Properties ["token"] = myToken;
```

Comment: So will this be applied in the Pcl? What happens if the user closes the application? Will the value be lost?

Comment: Yes, you use it in the shared project.  It is automatically persisted - I suggest you read the docs I linked to.

Comment: @Jason the docs only say it's persisted to the device. Do you have any idea where it's persisted? IE: Is it just some unencrypted flat file somewhere? Does it save them to the key store/key chain securely? I kind of doubt the security of storing secure tokens with this.

Comment: it is stored in your sandbox which is encrypted unless the device is jailbroken then it's no mans land

Answer (score 28):

Token(s) being sensitive information, I would recommend storing them in a secure manner. Secure storage is available through `Keychain` services in iOS, and the `KeyStore` class in Android. Xamarin has a very good [article](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/general/store-credentials/) on how to do that using `Xamarin.Auth`.

Other options available are:

1. `BlobCache.Secure` in [Akavache](https://github.com/akavache/Akavache)
2. [SecureStorage](https://github.com/sameerkapps/SecureStorage)
3. Secure storage in [XLabs](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs)

Answer (score 21):

Just an update for anyone searching, as things have changed since this post was created. It is not advised to use the following any more:

```
Application.Current.Properties
```

To securely store things like access tokens etc you can use the **Xamarin.Essentials** **SecureStorage** static class.

Just add the **Xamarin.Essentials** nuget package if you don't already have it and use it like so:

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;
.
.
.

await SecureStorage.SetAsync("someKey", "someValue");

var myValue = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("someKey");
```

you also have the option to

```
SecureStorage.Remove("someKey");
//or 
SecureStorage.RemoveAll();
```

[Refer this for more documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage)